# IPython Notebook and Git

Tags: git, version-control, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I do all my data analysis in IPython Notebook. For versioning, I just create separate Notebooks. I was wondering if there's any way to do version control in IPython Notebooks with Git. Or maybe some other solution that works equally well?

Edit to give more context: The problem with using Git with IPython Notebook is that the Notebooks contain a lot of non-Python data which I do not need to or want to track, but I do not know how to tell Git to not track such data. I'm looking for a solution that allows me to branch, merge and keep track of my commits.

Comment: What is the problem that this solution should solve, that you are facing with your current method?

Comment: @cel Yes. Thanks for pointing out. Should I just delete the question?